# What is the best way to insert a XML input to an oracle table in stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures, xml

I want to write a stored procedure which has a XML input (clob type) and inserts the data to a table. my XML structure is something like this:

```
<rowset>
    <row>
        <name>tom</name>
        <family>mack</family>
        ....
    </row> 
    <row>
        <name>marry</name>
        <family>skot</family>
        ....
    </row> 
    ...
</rowset>
```

I have just stock in many options that oracle gave me to handle this. using `extractvalue and XMLSequence`- using `DBMS_XMLDOM`- using `DBMS_XMLStore` or many other options.

I want to know which one is better according to the performance and resources that use. the input XML is usually less than 50KB.

Comment: To complex to understand . I made it simple for you. http://asporacle.com/2017/how-to-insert-xml-in-oracle-database-from-asp-net/118/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query your XML data directly in SQL with [`XMLTABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232):

```
SQL> VARIABLE xml VARCHAR2(4000);
SQL> BEGIN :xml :=
  2  '<rowset>
  3       <row>
  4           <name>tom</name>
  5           <family>mack</family>
  6       </row>
  7       <row>
  8           <name>marry</name>
  9           <family>skot</family>
 10       </row>
 11   </rowset>';
 12  END;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> SELECT x.*
  2    FROM XMLTable('for $i in /rowset/row return $i'
  3                    passing XMLTYPE(:xml) columns
  4                       name VARCHAR2(200) path 'name',
  5                       family VARCHAR2(200) path 'family'
  6                  ) x;

NAME    FAMILY
------- -------
tom     mack
marry   skot
```

You can also use [`XMLSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions251.htm#i1129570) and [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions060.htm#i1006712) (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/985985/119634) for example) but as noted in the documentation these functions are deprectated.

Another option is [`DBMS_XMLSTORE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_dbmstore.htm#CACEJGEH), although you can't really customize it much (needs perfect match between input xml tags and output column names):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE my_table ("name" VARCHAR2(10), "family" VARCHAR2(10));

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ctx  dbms_xmlstore.ctxtype;
  3     l_rows NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     l_ctx := dbms_xmlstore.newcontext('MY_TABLE'); -- Get saved context
  6     dbms_xmlstore.clearUpdateColumnList(l_ctx); -- Clear the update settings
  7  
  8     -- Set the columns to be updated/inserted as a list of values
  9     dbms_xmlstore.setUpdateColumn(l_ctx, 'name');
 10     dbms_xmlstore.setUpdateColumn(l_ctx, 'family');
 11     -- Set ROW tag
 12     dbms_xmlstore.setRowTag(l_ctx, 'row');
 13  
 14    -- Insert the doc.
 15    l_rows := DBMS_XMLSTORE.insertXML(l_ctx, :xml);
 16    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_rows || ' rows inserted.');
 17  
 18    -- Close the context
 19    DBMS_XMLSTORE.closeContext(l_ctx);
 20  
 21  END;
 22  /

2 rows inserted.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from my_table;

name       family
---------- ----------
tom        mack
marry      skot
```

I'm not sure performance-wise which option is faster, this certainly depends on the data -- you'll have to benchmark.